# Using std::swap on a vector of int

Tags: c++, vector, swap

I have a `vector` of int's... I just want to swap two values.

```
    std::vector<int> vec;

    vec.push_back(0);
    vec.push_back(1);
    vec.push_back(2);
    vec.push_back(3);
    vec.push_back(4);
    vec.push_back(5);
    vec.push_back(6);
    vec.push_back(7);
    vec.push_back(8);

    std::swap(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

Before the swap being called I have my vec as:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

After the `std::swap(...)` I was hoping to have the vec as:

```
[8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0]
```

But it remains as the initial state.
What is the problem here?

Comment: You're looking for [`std::iter_swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap), that swaps the dereferenced values. You also can not give it `vec.end()` as an argument.

Comment: Why does this even compile? `swap` requires lvalues as arguments, and `begin` and `end` yield rvalues. Is this MSVC with language extensions enabled?

Comment: @LogicStuff `iter_swap` won't help much if OP tries to use the `.end()` iterator

Comment: @vsoftco I've tried it with clang++ and g++ with libc++ and libstdc++ and it **did not compile**: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4bafc70816c9eba6

Comment: @dyp I take it back, I was dereferencing them. It would have been extremely weird to compile indeed. Probably OP is using MSVC which allows rvalue binding to non-const ref.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
assert(!vec.empty());
std::swap(vec.front(), vec.back());
```